# ColdFusion Calling CFC page for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Hey all I am trying to call the following cfm page in order to call a cfc page via ajax:

https://dev-thesite.com/personnel/search.cfm page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>      
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'search_ajax.cfc?method=searchAward',
        data: {
            Totals:'100', 
            CodeNum:'165161', 
            TestYear:'2016',
            SelType:'blah', 
            SelJuris:'juris'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('err: ', data);
        }
    });
 });     
 </script>
 <div id="testing"></div>
```

https://dev-thesite.com/personnel/search_ajax.cfc page:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="searchAward" access="remote" returntype="string">
            <cfargument name="Totals" type="string" required="true">
            <cfargument name="CodeNum" type="string" required="true">
            <cfargument name="TestYear" type="string" required="true">
            <cfargument name="SelType" type="string" required="true">
            <cfargument name="SelJuris" type="string" required="true"> 
        <cfscript>
            if(arguments.Totals = '5'){
                return 'YES!';
            } else {
                return 'NO!';
            }
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Currently when running this I get the **error** side of the ajax call.

> 500 - Internal server error.
>
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Any help would be great at fixing this error in ColdFusion 9!

Comment: Go into CFAdmin and enable debugging so that you can see the error. It looks like you're using an assignment statement instead of a comparison in your if clause.

Comment: Also, it looks like `arguments` needs to be `Arguments` according to [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a66e-7fe2.html)

Comment: Call the method directly from ColdFusion and see if the error occurs.

Comment: @DanBracuk yes, it does have the same 500 error when going to **https://dev-thesite.com/personnel/search_ajax.cfc?method=searchAward&Totals=100&CodeNum=165161&TestYear=2016&SelType=blah&SelJuris=juris**

Comment: You need to tick "Enable Robust Exception Information" under the Debugging Settings in CF Administrator to see what's going on. With a plain "500 Oops something went wrong" error, all bets are off.

Comment: @StealthRT - Dan probably meant call the function from CF, not via URL or browser. Debugging errors is almost always easier from CF than ajax/url. Run the function from a separate CF script. That would have indicated the code is trying to assign a value, rather than check equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like all that was wrong was changing this:

```
if(arguments.Totals = '5'){
```

to this:

```
if(arguments.Totals eq '5'){
```

Just adding the *eq* seems to have fixed it oddly enough.

Comment: `eq` is ColdFusion's traditional equality operator. From ColdFusion 9 onwards you can write it as `==` in `<cfscript>` sections. `=` is the assignment operator. I haven't spotted it, either. ([compare the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ff9))

Comment: Makes total sense. In the original you just had a var set to "5" - that's probably resulting in your 500 error.